# What are the benefits of using the co library with promises instead of with thunks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, thunk

So I've been reading about the usage of the [co](https://github.com/tj/co) library, and the general design pattern I've seen in most blog posts is wrapping functions that have callbacks in thunks. Then using an es6 generator to yield those thunks to the `co` object. Like this:

```
co(function *(){
  var a = yield read(‘Readme.md’);
  var b = yield read(‘package.json’);
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
});
function read(path) {
  return function(done){
    fs.readFile(path, ‘utf8', done);
  }
}
```

And that I can understand because it brings all the benefits of promises like better readability and better error handling.

But what's the point of using `co` if you already have promises available?

```
co(function* () {
  var res = yield [
    Promise.resolve(1),
    Promise.resolve(2),
    Promise.resolve(3),
  ];
  console.log(res); // => [1, 2, 3]
}).catch(onerror);
```

Why not something like

```
Promise.all([
  Promise.resolve(1),
  Promise.resolve(2),
  Promise.resolve(3),
]).then((res) => console.log(res)); // => [1, 2, 3]
}).catch(onerror);
```

To me, co makes the code look more confusing compared to the Promise version.

Comment: I haven't found any cases (ignoring es7) where it makes sense to me to use generators with promises. Most of the examples i've seen just make it more complicated just so that they can use generators.

Comment: co has it's uses, doesn't mean you use it everywhere even if it's not appropriate!

Comment: @KevinB for the es7 features are you referring to async/await or is there something else?

Comment: referring to async/await, it does allow for some cool things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No real cases, no. Unless you really hate the promise constructor (in which case, bluebird `promisify` to the rescue).

When you have Promises natively, nearly all valid usecases for callbacks that are called once with a single value are effectively moot.

Comment: What are your thoughts on bluebird vs native?

Comment: For server, bluebird all the way. For client, only if you want Promise support in older browsers (otherwise, the performance boost isn't worth the bytes you need to download)